Camundaworker not able install in Python Version 3.7.0
Camundaworker not able install  in Python Version 3.7.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement camunda-bpm-client
No module named 'camunda.worker'

I have tried with pip3 install camundaWorker command but facing issue
Python Version 3.7.0

Where did you get the instruction to pip3 install camundaWorker? There is no package by that name in PyPI.

@AKX  from chatgpt

Well, ChatGPT lied to you then, as it tends to do.

I don't know anything about Camunda, but chances are you want this package and you should follow its instructions.

I fixed this issue By using pycamunda.externaltask.
